# How to output a multiline equation with no margins

Tags: margins, standalone, preview

I'm trying to output a .pdf that just contains an equation, without any borders at all, or borders the same width all the way round.

So far, I've tried two things.  Using the `standalone` document class, and using the `preview` package.  The first one doesn't quite suit my needs because you can't use the `equation` or `align` environments so you can't put in multi-line, aligned equations.

The second technique is better, but the resulting pdf has whitespace to the left of the equation instead of having no border at all.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,displaymath]{preview}

%\PreviewBorder=1pt &setting this to 0 doesn't remove the margin on the left

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 E_i = &E_{Z} + E_{an} + E_{ex}\\ 
     = &- \mu_0 M_{s, i} H cos (\phi_i)\\
       &+ K_{u,i} sin^2(\phi_i - \theta)\\
       &- J_{i+1} \mu_0 M_{s, i} M_{s, i+1} cos(\phi_i - \phi_{i+1})\\
       &- J_{i-1} \mu_0 M_{s, i} M_{s, i-1} cos(\phi_i - \phi_{i-1})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I hope the question is clear enough.  Let me know if not.

Comment: not sure what the purpose of this question is, but if the idea is to get a small `.pdf` file that can be included somewhere else, what i'd do is, first, add `\thispagestyle{empty} just after `\begin{document}`, and then use (from the command line) `pdfcrop -margin 3 filename.pdf`.  this will produce a file `filename-crop.pdf` that is tightly cropped on all edges; the small margin is added to avoid skiving off the edges of those glyphs that touch the margins.

Comment: @barbara That was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm sure there's another question already that answers this, but i can't find it.

if the idea is to get a small `.pdf` file to include somewhere else, there are two
steps to follow:

- make sure the output doesn't have anything extraneous, like a page number.  to do
  this, add `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after `\begin{document}`.
- when you have the minimal `.pdf` file, run this from the command line:

  `pdfcrop -margin 3 filename.pdf`

  the small margin is added to avoid skiving off the edges of those glyphs that touch
  the margins.

this will produce a file `filename-crop.pdf` that is tightly cropped on all edges.