# Package or setting required for proper aligned equations

Tags: packages

I've installed [Tex2png](https://github.com/Gregwar/Tex2png), a PHP-based solution to produce png math images.

Simple expressions render fine, but some environments do not (with unhelpful "LaTeX error" messages).

It seems my Linux server had very few packages. I unzipped these:

1. amsmath
2. amscls
3. tools

to

/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local

This got some expressions to at least render something, but not correctly. For example, this:

```
\begin{aligned}\text{Vol}&=\pi\int_1^b{\frac{1}{x}}^2dx\\ &=\pi\int_1^b{x^{-2}}dx\\ &=\pi\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_1^b\\ &=\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)\end{aligned}
```

gives this (partial screen shot), with everything horizontal:

[image: horizontal equation]

I've tried \align, \align*, \aligned and \aligned*, but they either give "LaTeX error" or the vertical alignment is ignored. So presumably I'm missing a package or two, but I thought amsmath and tools should handle most of these cases.

I don't know:

1. Which packages are already on the server
2. Whether I've unzipped the packages to the right places
3. Which packages I need add to address the above

Any pointers would be very welcome.

Comment: Align etc. are all environments.  While environments are implemented using macros (\align and \endalign), you need both.   Note that amsmath and mathtools come with manuals on their use.

Comment: Thanks, John. I know enough LaTeX to be dangerous - not enough yet to master it. All working OK now.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite an answer to your question.  I don't have or know much about Tex2png.  It seems to me that perhaps Tex2png is limited in the extent to what sorts of *environments* it can handle.  Namely, it looks like it doesn't handle math environments very well.

But, you can create something similar just running `pdflatex`.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{math}
\begin{aligned}
  \text{Vol}&=\pi\int_1^b{\frac{1}{x}}^2dx      \\ 
            &=\pi\int_1^b{x^{-2}}dx             \\ 
            &=\pi\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_1^b  \\ 
            &=\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{math}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Granted, this will be a `pdf` document.  Perhaps you can use it as is.  But, if you actually need to work with a `png`, there are various tools available that will allow you to convert from one kind of format to another.

The provided solution to [How to output a multiline equation with no margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237167/22413) may be of interest to you.

The solution to [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11880/22413) also talks about how to convert between file formats.

**Using other environments**

If you want to use other environments like `align`, then you can still do something similar, but you will need to somehow pass `align` a page width to work with.  That can be achieved by using the `preview` option passed to the documentclass:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,preview]{standalone}
```

Since you're likely to get an image much wider than you want with this approach, look at the answer provided in the first link suggested above.

However, there is a work around.  You could put the `align` environment within a `minipage` and do something like the following

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\start@align{%
  \if@minipage\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip\fi
}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.2in}
\begin{align*}
  \text{Vol}&=\pi\int_1^b{\frac{1}{x}}^2dx      \\ 
            &=\pi\int_1^b{x^{-2}}dx             \\ 
            &=\pi\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_1^b  \\ 
            &=\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I believe the `minipage` width here is not really a concern if all you're going to do is create the environment for displaying mathematics.

Now, there is some extra code here that makes this look a bit complicated.  Namely, the code starting from `\makeatletter`.  This is to get around a peculiar issue in which the `align*` environment expects  it's being called midparagraph.  Therefore, `align*` adds extra whitespace at the top of the environment.  For details about this *workaround* see egreg's solution to [Spurious space above align environment at top of page/minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36963/22413).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. There were so many things going wrong it was hard to pin down the root cause and I concluded it was a package problem. Turns out it was 2 issues: Not handling double backslash correctly; and there was an errant extra bracket in my expression. So all is good, finally. Thanks again.